# Select unique value pairs based on two participants that occur more than once inside a table

Tags: mysql

We are using MySQL where we have **deals** table that contains references to two users stored in two columns User_id1 & User_id2. There is no guaranty in which order those are stored. For example the records below represent a deal between two unique pair of users

```
id ... User_id1 User_id2
-- --- -------- --------
 1 ...       11       20
 2 ...       20       11
 3 ...      116     3459
 4 ...       20       11
```

We need an SQL query to migrate this data into two new tables below

**Participants**

```
chat_id user_id
------- -------
      1      11
      1      20
      2     116
      2    3459
```

**Chat_rooms**

```
id
--
 1
 2
```

For each unique pair of users in **deals** table, we need to create a unique conversation record in **Chat_rooms** table and add those two users as participants to the **Participants** table with the reference to the created Chat_room ID

I'm hopping to do this with SQL, potentially using some temporary tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW uniqueness (id, User_id1, User_id2)
AS
SELECT MIN(id), 
       LEAST(User_id1, User_id2) User_id1,  
       GREATEST(User_id1, User_id2) User_id2
GROUP BY LEAST(User_id1, User_id2),  
         GREATEST(User_id1, User_id2);
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO Chat_rooms (id) SELECT id FROM uniqueness;
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Participants (chat_id, user_id)
SELECT id, User_id1 FROM uniqueness
UNION ALL
SELECT id, User_id2 FROM uniqueness;
```

---

You may create temporary table instead of view

-- or --

You may insert view's source text into INSERT queries

Comment: I don't think `chat_id` is supposed to originally come from the `deals` table (the reference to which, by the way, is missing from the view).  From the data samples in the question, it looks more like they are just new IDs assigned arbitrarily across all the unique pairs.  Other than that, I completely agree with the approach.